# Find all functions $f∶ \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that, for all $n \in \Bbb N, \left[\frac{{f(x+n) - f(x-n)}}{{2n}} = f'(x)\right]$

Tags: functions, derivatives, functional-equations, delay-differential-equations

There was a similar question in the Putnam ($2010$ A$2$) but I can't wrap my head around this one. I've tried attacking it in some standard ways of eliminating arbitrary functions but it doesn't seem to be an easy manipulation. Also noticed that this is the expression for the average rate change of a differentiable function in the interval $[x-n,x+n]$ but again don't know how I can use that information. Linear and quadratic functions seem to fit the bill but how do you find the other ones or prove that these are the only kinds?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Certainly, functions of the form $f(x) = ax+b$ meet the criteria.  The harder part would be to prove that only functions of the form $f(x) = ax+b$ will work.

Comment: Presumably you mean for all real numbers $x$ and for all integers $n$, ...

Comment: Could you please share more information like your thoughts and ideas behind the DDE so that we can really help you, not just solve the task and the question meets the quality standards for Math.SE.

Comment: @fredgoodman Putting zero for $n$ would give a zero denominator. And negative $n$ would not add anything since the statement is symmetric around $0$ in $n.$ I agree about the for all real $x.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $$f'(x) = \frac12 \Big(f(x+1)-f(x-1)\Big).$$
As $f$ is differentiable, it follows that $\frac12 (f(x+1)-f(x-1))$ is differentiable, so $f'$ is differentiable.  Let's differentiate it!
$$\begin{align*}
f''(x) &= \frac12 \Big(f'(x+1)-f'(x-1)\Big) \\
&= \frac12 \left(\frac12\Big(f(x+2)-f(x)\Big) - \frac12\Big(f(x)-f(x-2)\Big)\right) \\
&= \frac14\Big(f(x+2)-2f(x)+f(x-2)\Big).
\end{align*}$$

Once again, we note that since $f$ is differentiable, the expression on the right side of this equation is differentiable, so $f''$ is differentiable.  Differentiating again yields
$$\begin{align*}
f'''(x) &= \frac14\Big(f'(x+2)-2f'(x)+f'(x-2)\Big) \\
 &= \frac14\left(\frac12\Big(f(x+3)-f(x+1)\Big) - \frac22\Big(f(x+1)-f(x-1)\Big) + \frac12\Big(f(x-1)-f(x-3)\Big)\right) \\
&= \frac18\Big(f(x+3)-3f(x+1) + 3f(x-1)-f(x-3)\Big) \\
&= \frac18\Big(\big(f(x+3)-f(x-3)\big) - 3\big(f(x+1)-f(x-1)\big)\Big) \\
&= \frac18(6f'(x)-6f'(x)) = 0.
\end{align*}$$

---

In particular, this shows that if $f$ is differentiable and $$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+n)-f(x-n)}{2n}$$ for every real $x$ and for $n \in \{1,3\},$ then $f$ is thrice-differentiable and $f'''(x) = 0$.

By integrating (or equivalently, applying the mean value theorem to the derivatives of $f(x)-f(0)-f'(0)x-\frac12f''(0)x^2$), we see that $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$.

To finish, it suffices to check that every quadratic function satisfies the given condition for any natural number $n$.

Comment: I guess it also assumes that the function $f$ is at least thrice-differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, though perhaps this can be weakened to just assuming $f$ is once-differentiable using a density argument.

Comment: @4plus4man If $f$ is differentiable, then so is $\frac12 (f(x+1)-f(x-1))$ (and we know what its derivative looks like) .  Inductively, it follows that $f$ is differentiable of every order.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing the answer from Brian Moehring, we have $f'''(x) = 0$. Assuming $f(x)$ has a convergent Taylor series at $x$, we have,

$$f(x) = a+bx+cx^2$$
$$f'(x) = b+2cx$$
$$f(x+n)-f(x-n) = b2n + c((x+n)^2-(x-n)^2) = b2n + c(4nx)$$

Hence $\frac{f(x+n)-f(x-n)}{2n} = b+2cx = f'(x)$.

So any function of the form $f(x) = a + bx + cx^2$ will work.

Comment: Note that $f'''(x)=0$ is strictly stronger than having a convergent Taylor series.  As long as the domain is an interval, the mean value theorem (or equivalently, standard integration techniques) suffices to show $f$ is quadratic.